# system-independent find following symbolic links?

Tags: find

I want to use the 'find' command and have it follow symbolic links.  However, I need to call the command from other code (IDL, which doesn't have very nice built-in file searching) on both a RedHat and a Mac OS X system.

The problem is, the RedHat system uses GNU find version 4.1.20, while the mac find is some BSD version.  In mac find, you use `find -L` to follow symlinks.  In the GNU version, you use `find -follow`.  There don't appear to be any common options between the two for following symbolic links.

A workaround for my machines is to change the `find` to a private version of my own, but that is not an acceptable option for distributing the code.  Can anyone recommend alternatives?  Is there something in the `find` manual I missed telling how to follow symbolic links that does not depend on the version?

Comment: You should past that as an answer and not as an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just using find incorrectly.

This fails:

```
$ find -follow . -name "t*"
find: ollow: No such file or directory
```

While this works:

```
$ find . -name "t*" -follow
```

I think it's because -f is a special option to find.

Note that the GNU version of find also does not allow -follow before the path, but it at least gives a useful error:

```
find: paths must precede expression
```

Comment: This is what the second line of `man find` has to say about this: `find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]`. The path always comes before the search expression...